# php - create ics file dynamically and email as attachment

Tags: php, google-calendar-api, sendgrid

I need to create a calendar invite dynamically and email the ics file as an attachment. I'm using sendgrid to send emails.

This is my php script currently:

```
include("/Users/path/sendgrid-php.php");
$sendgrid = new SendGrid("uname", "pass");
$email    = new SendGrid\Email();

$ical = "BEGIN:VCALENDAR
VERSION:2.0
PRODID:-//hacksw/handcal//NONSGML v1.0//EN
BEGIN:VEVENT
UID:" . md5(uniqid(mt_rand(), true)) . "@test.com
DTSTAMP:" . gmdate('Ymd').'T'. gmdate('His') . "Z
DTSTART:19970714T170000Z
DTEND:19970715T035959Z
SUMMARY:New event
END:VEVENT
END:VCALENDAR";

header('Content-type: text/calendar; charset=utf-8');
header('Content-Disposition: inline; filename=invite.ics');

$email->addTo("test@test.com")
    ->setFrom("test2@test2.com")
    ->setSubject("Test-Subject")
    ->setHtml("Test-Body")
    ->setAttachment($ical);

$sendgrid->send($email);
```

Now, whenever I run this script, instead of sending the ics file as an attachment to the email address provided, my browser automatically downloads the ics file, closes the page, and doesn't do anything (no email is sent).

Can you all please tell me where am I going wrong here? I've just started with PHP so chances are likely that I must have made some silly error.

Thanks.

Comment: Have you tried removing the two `header(…)` lines?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The behavior you are seeing is being triggered by your `header()` calls.

```
header('Content-type: text/calendar; charset=utf-8');
header('Content-Disposition: inline; filename=invite.ics');
```

Those 2 lines are sending headers to the client browser and triggering the download.

In the [SendGrid PHP examples](https://sendgrid.com/docs/Code_Examples/php.html) I don't see them setting headers like that at all.